# Disable autocorrect in macOS Notes app

Tags: macos, autocorrect, system-preferences, apple-notes

I am struggling to disable autocorrect in the Notes app in macOS. I did:

`System Preferences > Keyboard > Text` tab, uncheck `Correct spelling automatically`.

and it works well for other parts of macOS. But in Notes, autocorrect still happens all the time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While in Notes, take a look at:

```
Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Correct Spelling Automatically
```

…and make sure it's un-checked.

You might also want to disable some automatic substitutions under:

```
Edit > Substitutions > [various items]
```

Comment: Just to note: this is individually switchable in many Mac apps, TextEdit saves it per document [which can be irritating;)

Comment: Aha I understood and changed it. This really helped, thank you guys!

Comment: Super helpful :D thx! These "Spelling and Grammar" settings were greyed out for me at first, because i think you have to have a note open whereas i just had the Notes application open

Answer (score 1):

If you're hitting this even after changing the system-wide setting, be sure to uncheck "Correct Spelling Automatically" in the Edit menu here:
[image: How to disable spelling correction in Apple Notes app]

This setting isn't editable in Notes -> Settings, so it took me a while to find it at first.